# Fastest algorithm for splitting a string in C?

Tags: c, string, algorithm, command-line-interface, tokenize

I'm writing a CLI input parser and I want to know what is the fastest algorithm to split a string into tokens.

Rules:

- A space means end of the token.
- Any char can be escaped with a backslash which means that I take it as is without any specal meaning. (currently only used for escaping a space)

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
#define POINTER_ARRAY_STEP 10
#define STRING_STEP 255

char **parse_line(char *line)
{
    char **array;
    size_t array_len;
    size_t array_index;
    size_t token_len;
    size_t token_index;

    array_len = POINTER_ARRAY_STEP;
    array = malloc((array_len + 1) * sizeof(char*)); /* +1 to leave space for NULL */
    array_index = 0;

    token_len = STRING_STEP;
    array[array_index] = malloc(token_len + 1);
    token_index = 0;

    for (; *line; ++line) {
        if (array_index == array_len) {
            array_len += POINTER_ARRAY_STEP;
            array = realloc(array, (array_len + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        }
        if (token_index == token_len) {
            token_len += STRING_STEP;
            array[array_index] = realloc(array[array_index], token_len + 1);
        }
        if (*line == '\\') {
            array[array_index][token_index++] = *++line;
            continue;
        }
        if (*line == ' ') {
            array[array_index][token_index] = 0;
            array[++array_index] = malloc(token_len + 1);
            token_index = 0;
            continue;
        }
        array[array_index][token_index++] = *line;
    }
    /* Null terminate the last array element */
    array[array_index][token_index] = 0;

    /* Null terminate the array */
    array[array_index + 1] = NULL;
    return array;
}
```

Comment: `foo = realloc(foo, some_size)` is always a bad idea: if the call fails you'd have to free the original pointer `foo`, which you have just written over.

Comment: @DanielJour yes, and for performance sake, reallocating one by one isn't optimal either. That's the difference between the size and the capacity.

Comment: The fastest of *which* algorithms? It depends on whether you are prepared to sacrifice the input string, as `strtok` does. My choice would be to advance through the string with `strchr` and write nul terminators into the spaces of the (copy of the) string.

Comment: apart from that I'd say it belongs more to codereview

Comment: I don't reallocate one by one only once per ten tokens look at the value of the POINTER_ARRAY_STEP macro.

Comment: Also you could consider getting that allocation and reallocation logic out of that function.

Comment: You don't need to reallocate. You can just remember the beginning of the word, find the end, and allocate the memory you need.

Comment: Finally: when asking for the "fastest algorithm" there's always the question: did you profile your (working?) implementation? Is it actually a bottleneck?

Comment: There are usually very few reasons to replace `flex`-generated parsers with custom-made parsers. Do you have a reason to believe that a `flex`-based parser for your project is inefficient?

Comment: I'd recommend running the program under valgrind or address sanitizer to get rid of the out-of-bounds accesses.

Comment: Hmmm"(currently only used for escaping a space)" I'd expect the backslash escape character to escape a space _and_ at least a following backslash.

Comment: Only used in practice for escaping spaces it actually escapes everything just fine.

Comment: Hmm, Doubt it escape the _null character_ fine.  `array[array_index][token_index++] = *++line;` will venture passed the end of the string.

Comment: How should 2 successive space be interpreted? or  line that begins with a space, or a line that ends with a space?

Comment: `... (currently only used for escaping a space)` If you are planning to extend this *parser*, you should consider creating a DFA (or use (f)lex to do that for you). Also: put the string-array management stuff into separate functions, and inline them.

Comment: Is what you have not fast enough?  Can you not use strtok?

Comment: The fastest algorithm is a suffix tree. But that;s not what you want. Just hand-write a lexer which escapes strings and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is both unsafe and inefficient: you do not check for memory allocation failure and you call `realloc()` way too many times.

Here is another approach:

- make a first pass to count the number of tokens and escapes,
- allocate the pointer array and a buffer for the tokens
- make a second pass, copying the characters into the buffer, splitting the tokens and making the pointer array point to the tokens.
- return the array pointer.

The memory can later be freed by calling `free()` on both the pointer array and its first element.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char **parse_line(const char *line) {
    size_t len, i, j, k, items = 1, escapes = 0;
    char **array;
    char *buf;

    for (len = 0; line[len]; len++) {
        if (line[len] == '\\') {
            escapes++;
            if (line[++len] == '\0')
                break;
        } else
        if (line[len] == ' ') {
            items++;
        }
    }
    if (len == escapes) {
        /* special case empty line */
        array = malloc(sizeof(*array));
        if (array != NULL) {
            array[0] = NULL;
        }
        return array;
    }
    array = malloc((items + 1) * sizeof(*array));
    buf = malloc(len + 1 - escapes);

    if (array == NULL || buf == NULL) {
        free(array);
        free(buf);
        return NULL;
    }
    items[0] = buf;
    k = 1;
    for (i = j = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (line[i] == '\\') {
            if (++i == len)
                break;
            buf[j++] = line[i];
        } else
        if (line[i] == ' ') {
            buf[j++] = '\0';
            items[k++] = buf + j;
        } else {
            buf[j++] = line[i];
        }
    }
    buf[j] = '\0';
    items[k] = NULL;
    return items;
}
```

Comment: I'd say this was very intelligently designed.  (suggest `free(array);` --> `free(array);free(buf);`)

Comment: BTW: I think the `items` is 1 too small.  Consider a line with no spaces/no escapes.

Comment: @chux: good point, we do not know which `malloc()` failed.  I already updated the special case of the empty line.

Answer (score 2):

Suggested fastest algorithm

Make only 2 passes.  Once to find token count and length of buffer needed.

2nd time to chop up duplicated line.

The array of tokens point to a single allocated memory, so when done, `tokens[0]` needs to be free'd as well as `tokens`.

As OP asked for a faster *algorithm*, below is $pseudo code$/code.

```
char **parse_line(const char *line) {
  size_t token_count = 1;
  const char *p = line;
  $Let `p` each element in `line`$
    $if `*p` is a separator, increment `token_count`
    $else `*p` is an escape not followed by a \0$
      $advance `p`$
    }
  }

  $ `p`, at the end of the string, so allocate enough for a    $
  $ duplicate +1 based on the difference of `p` and the start. $
  $ Check allocation success                                   $ 
  $ Copy into `char *line_buffer`                              $

  // The token count is known, get enough pointers + 1 and check
  char **tokens = malloc(sizeof *tokens * (token_count + 1));

  // More complex code could perform only 1 allocation for `tokens` and `line_buffer`

  $ Let `q` be first element in line_buffer
  $ Let `d` be the same (destination pointer)
  $ set begin_token flag $
  size_t token_index = 0;
  for (;;) {
    $ if begin_token flag set $ {
      $ clear begin_token $
      tokens[token_index] = q;
      d = q;
    }
    $ if `*q` separator (space or \0) $ {
      *d = '\0';
      token_index++;
      $ if *q at end of string $ break;
      $ set begin_token flag $
    $else {
      if `*q` is an escape not followed by a \0$
        $advance q$
      }
      $copy *q to *d, advance both pointers.
    }
  }
  $set last tokens[] to NULL$
  return tokens;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I came up with the same idea and then saw your deleted answer...

Comment: @chqrlie [imitation is the sincerest form of flattery](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/imitation-is-the-sincerest-form-of-flattery). ;-)

Comment: Just wondering, why did you write pseudo code? Did you think the OP was asking for homework help?

Comment: @chqrlie Post was about _algorithm_ and the code looked fun to do, so I did it, but did not want to give away too much.

Comment: Indeed the OP asked for *the fastest algorithm* which is a not exactly the same as *an efficient implementation*, although the latter is probably what he was really asking for. I tend to read the questions less acutely than the code.